# MySQL date range display errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a bit of help checking my SQL query.

I have a database that stores some  information in two tables and one table has a column with the date the person signed up. I want to be able to retrieve some of the information of the people who signed up within a specific date range.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT personal_info.member_id, personal_info.surname, personal_info.first_name, personal_info.phone_number, personal_info.email_address, personal_info.postal_address, church_info.received_date
FROM personal_info, church_info
WHERE personal_info.member_id = church_info.member_id
    AND church_info.received_date between '$startdate' AND '$enddate'
```

My issue is sometimes when I enter a date range nothing is retrieved and other times it includes some dates that are not within the specified range. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the data type of `received_date` and what do `$startdate` and `$enddate` look like?  Often this happens when a `date` -- horror of horrors -- is stored in the database using strings.

Comment: use inner join instead

Comment: It's a `VARCHAR` datatype ...

Comment: @GordonLinoff, would you please elaborate more on the passing of the date as a string? Also `$startdate` and `$enddate` are entered in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` as that it the way it appears in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the dates in the database are stored as strings and not dates.  Hence, string comparisons are used.  And, worse, instead of using the ISO standard syntax of YYYY-MM-DD, you are putting the days first.  That is like counting days in the years as Jan 1, Feb 1, Mar 1, . . ., Dec 1, Jan 2, Feb 2.  An awful format for dates.  Use the native formats.  That is what they are there for.  If you have control over the database, fix the data formats in the database so they accurately reflect the values being stored.

If not, you can fix your problem using the `str_to_date()` function:

```
str_to_date(church_info.received_date, '%d/%m/%Y') between
         str_to_date('$startdate', '%d/%m/%Y') AND str_to_date('$enddate', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

For the constants, though, I would just fix them in the application.  MySQL will automatically and correctly convert a string constant in the format of YYYY-MM-DD to a date when it is expecting a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you may have an issue if you declared the received_date as DATETIME

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        personal_info.member_id, 
        personal_info.surname, 
        personal_info.first_name, 
        personal_info.phone_number, 
        personal_info.email_address, 
        personal_info.postal_address, 
        church_info.received_date
    FROM personal_info
    LEFT JOIN church_info ON personal_info.member_id = church_info.member_id
    WHERE 
          AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(church_info.received_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) between '$startdate'
          AND '$enddate'";
```

Comment: the datatype is VARCHAR, and when I tried your suggestion I got this error - Could not get data: Unknown column 'church_info.received_date' in 'where clause'.

Comment: VARCHAR? you should use the `date` or `datetime` datatype. It will interpret the field as a string.

Comment: And to be more exact you should used join, i recommend you to show us your sample database here : http://sqlfiddle.com/ . I will show you after i will see your database.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I changed the format to `DATE` and it's working as it should now.